# strange behaviour requiring images with dynamic paths / names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, require

I currently ask myself why this is working:

```
const imagePath = "a.jpg" 
const aimg = require(`../../assets/images/${imagePath}`)
```

while this does not work:

```
const imagePath = "../../assets/images/" 
const aimg = require(`${imagePath}a.jpg`)
```

Those paths will be applied inside the render method of a react component (using jsx):

```
render() {
  return (
    <img src={aimg} />
  )
}
```

What is the reason for this? From my point of view both cases just append some strings and pass it to the `require()` method.

Comment: I think that if that's really happening, it has something to do with stuff that RequireJS does. I haven't used it so I'm not sure but I *think* it "looks" at your code to do some sort of optimization or transformation or something.

Comment: @Pointy it seems to me this is more related to something like webpack or rollup

Comment: This is the dynamic import problem, hence they're working on having the import() function and such. When you transpile the code (which react will do), require() will try to resolve those paths, but the script isn't actually running so the variables are undefined. Depending on a bunch of things like which bundler is used and which other npm modules you have, it might or might not work. Stuff like webpack has like `require( 'str' + var + 'str' );`, but that has other caveats.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts sure; as I said I'm not a RequireJS user so I don't know specifics.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts i am using webpack